# "com_error" when trying to output pdf from excel file using win32com

Tags: python, excel, pdf, win32com

I am trying to use win32com to print excel file to pdf format. However, I am getting this error:

File "", line 15, in 
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)

File "<COMObject >", line 4, in ExportAsFixedFormat

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Code snippet:

```
from win32com import client                    

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")   
excel.Visible = False  
wb_path = 'C:/Users/workbook.xlsm'
                               
path_to_pdf = 'C:/Users/test.pdf'                              

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)                    

ws_index_list = [1]

wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
```

Comment: It may be that you don't have write permission in 'C:/Users' Try writing it in your local directory.

Comment: Thank you. I tried another folder it finally worked.